# Is there any reason to choose a training strategy other than Use Facilities?

Tags: pocket-league-story

In Pocket League Story, there are three options for training strategy (in the menu, select View Info, then Coach Info). I've listed the options below with the text the game displays when you choose one.

- Team Practice (practice on the field; select this when you want to get experience points)
- Player's Choice (up to the players whether they want to use the facilities or practice on the field; if you're not sure, this might not be a bad choice)
- Use Facilities (use the facilities on the grounds, use this when you want to get a lot of research points)

The [official guide](http://kairospot.net/pocket-league-story-guide/) on Kairosoft's website has this to say under Tips & Tricks, General Hints:

> Always have your training strategy set to **Use Facilities**, as you will have heavy reliance on research points throughout the game, so it is important to generate as many as possible.

Is there ever a point in the game where I'd want experience instead of research? Official guides aren't always "right" – it's not uncommon for players to find optimal strategies other than those intended by the developers – but in this case, I can't find an issue with their logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time I can see that it would be worthwhile to do team practice is once ALL of the following conditions are met:

1) You've unlocked everything that requires Hearts or Lightbulbs (ie. Training Methods, Facilities, Sponsors).

2) All of your players have reached max stats or their capped stats (eliminating the need for Field, Strength or Light Bulbs).

3) You have the maximum amount of fans, support and fame (eliminating the need for Hearts).

4) You still have players under level 30.